# How to get the full path when the file is uploaded?

Tags: java, html, file, servlets, upload

I am having the *Servlet* web application which have upload functionality.

> I am checking one condition that file name should contain .csv. If it having .csv the process continues otherwise I am displaying error screen.

But, the issue is it is working fine in my system(Local) but in test environment I am getting the error screen. So I want to see the actual path where the file is uploaded.

So please suggest me how to get the path where file is uploaded. I can print it in log and I will able to find the solution for the above issue.

In Short, How to get the file path when the file is uploaded?(**Servlet/Java**).

```
Ex: c:/Project/Upload/... etc
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far? The code that works and the tests that fail.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857302/how-to-retrieve-full-path-of-uploaded-file-in-jsp-java

Comment: @Raf Yes. It got failed in test. So I want to see the full path where it is uploaded.

Comment: that's in server location mnt//testfile. I want the path where the file stored in my computer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
File.getAbsolutePath()
```

Or maybe you don't have the file?
To find the path to your war file that has been deployed onto the server, you can do something like this:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("a_file_in_your_resources_folder_.txt");
```

Comment: Can you provide me the exact line of code what I need to do?

Comment: Its not working. Is it possible to get the file location which is stored in my computer via servlet program